# Unable to get an appointment at San Francisco Italy Consulate

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, san-francisco, consulates

I am only a permanent resident of the United states so I need to apply for a Schengen visa. I'm going on a guided tour of several countries in Europe with a large group and we are staying the most days in Italy

I have 38 days before my trip to acquire a visa from the General Consulate of Italy in San Francisco but the next available appointment is the beginning of August and I'm supposed to leave on July 4. Please, please let me know if you have been in a similar situation and have they ever allowed someone to apply for a Schengen visa without an appointment?

Comment: Are you staying almost as many days in some second country that may have a shorter wait?

Comment: When I went to the Italian consulate in NYC, they said that they release a few extra appointments each evening at 6pm for the next day. Maybe SF does something similar. Also, cancelled appointments might free up something, so keep checking.

Answer (score 2):

It is too late now, but since you mention several countries you might have been able to change the Consulate you needed to apply to by breaking from the group briefly. You have not provided specific details and presumably never will but perhaps one extra day in a country other than Italy at the expense of a day in Italy would have been enough to make that other country the one in which you were scheduled to spend the most days.

Comment: (+1) Another option could be to apply at another Italian consulate, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t/51242#51242