# Can I get an appointment at a French consulate different than the one assigned to my state?

Tags: visas, schengen

I got invitation to visit a French school last week and have to be there in September. I am unable to get an appointment at the French consulate in NYC for the next two months. Can I request another French consulate to help and give an appointment as I definitely need it earlier?

Comment: Are you lawfully resident in the US? In which state?

Comment: Yes, I am a resident in CT lawfully.

Comment: What sort of invitation is that? A regular academic conference for which you submitted an abstract? Some sort of invitation to give a keynote speech or guest lecture from someone you know? In the latter case, you could ask them to see if they can try to contact the foreign ministry about the issue? They won't ignore the rules but a school with some clout might help move things along (e.g. by securing an early appointment directly)

Comment: Thanks. It is a regular academic conference though. I fail to understand how they can have 2-3 month waiting time for visa appointments. Basically, I can never attend any event in France with that waiting time.

Comment: @user56199 Budget cuts and a general lack of concern for foreigners (the way people who need to renew a residence permit are treated in some parts of France is a disgrace). That said, the summer holiday season might make things more complicated and NYC is a big one, not all consulates have such a long waiting time all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, that's not allowed. The relevant Schengen regulation does leave the door open in special circumstances, but that's not how French consulates traditionally work. You have to apply to the consulate serving your place of residence and cannot simply choose one that's convenient for you, even in the same country.

However, it does not hurt to ask, either by trying to contact the NYC consulate directly or by lodging an application at another consulate, explaining why you do that (you can write a short letter to join to your application). Since it's a reasonable reason and it's out of your control, they might agree to see it as a valid justification to apply article 6(2) of the Schengen visa code but it's really up to them (see also [Can I apply for Schengen visa from London as foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47223/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-from-london-as-foreigner/47225#47225) and [Can we apply for a Schengen tourist visa while visiting another country on a short-stay visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london/48757#48757)).

Some practical tips: Always be congenial and to-the-point in your communication, do not suggest you feel entitled to something or get angry – even if you have good reasons to! – but stand your ground and don't be obsequious either and you might get lucky. But it's a long shot.

Comment: Thanks. I sent a to-the-point email to Boston Consulate and they agreed. So, I guess it can work if one has important reasons :-)