# Can I apply to France (Schengen visa) when my main destination is Germany because I can't book an appointment at the German consulate?

Tags: schengen, france, schengen-visas

I know the rule is to apply at the consulate of the country which is either your only/longest stay, or of first entry if all stays are equal in terms of purpose and length.

My itinerary goes like this:

1. 4 nights in France (tourism)
2. 7 nights in Germany (tourism + take the opportunity to visit a fair related to my business/where I'm registered as a trade visitor).

I've been told that the business aspect of the trip will seem like the main purpose and therefore I should apply at the German consulate, even though the reason why I'm traveling is tourism (and I'm paying for the whole thing from my personal account). So I tried to book an appointment with the German consulate, but the first appointment in my country is a week after I'm supposed to return from my trip (in 3+ months). My only chance is to apply at the French consulate, I'm just worried they'd reject me because it doesn't seem like/isn't the main destination.

What should I do?

Comment: We have heard from people who tried this and were refused.

Comment: As in the consulate refused to process their application, or was their visa rejected? Also, would changing my itinerary (so they're an equal number of days) help?

Comment: Another option: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t

Comment: @Relaxed brings up a good possibility. Under the circumstances, a different German consulate in your country might be willing to accommodate you.

Comment: In principle, they should refuse to process the application (let you know quickly/refund the fee/return the documents). Applying to the wrong consulate is *not* grounds for denying a visa and should not be a black mark on your record.

Comment: @Relaxed The problem is that visa applications are only processed by the local German embassy, and there is nowhere else in my country where I can submit a visa application to Germany. Unless you mean writing a letter with my application to the French consulate?

Comment: @egyptianlamp Seems even less likely to work but you could always try that as well. What I meant is trying to find another German consulate. It could even be in another country (although if you live in Egypt, I can't think of a convenient one you could go to without significant costs and inconvenience).

Comment: The technical term for this is 'visa shopping'.

Comment: @GayotFow As I understand, visa shopping is when you're refused a visa by a member state so you apply at another. I wasn't refused a visa; the nearest possible appointment is in more than 3 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that applying to the French consulate is fraught with difficulty and likely not to work. But you could try, if you are completely upfront (don't cheat and lie about your intentions), you don't risk a refusal (which would have all sorts of unpleasant circumstances) but only a rejection (the consulate will promptly decline to process your application and you should get your fee and documents back). If you try this, join a letter explaining why to your application, it might help too.

A few other things you might try is [finding another German consulate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t) (if needed in a neighbouring country you can access easily) or keep watching the schedule to see if new appointment slots open.

In any case, three month waiting time is not acceptable (people are not supposed to apply more than three months in advance!) so you can certainly try to contact the German consulate (politely, don't act entitled or angry even if you and I know they are at fault) and ask if they can suggest a solution.

Comment: I'll try again with the German consulate (closest neighboring country is Libya and their German embassy delegated their visa applications to Cairo though so I'll be trying the local one) and if it doesn't work out, I'll be upfront with the French consulate. If they accept, great. If they don't, I'll change my itinerary (= my actual plan, as I will not be committing fraud) so France is my main destination. Thank you.

Comment: @egyptianlamp I am not sure about applying twice to the French consulate. You can try one or the other but doing both risk giving the appearance that you don't have any genuine plan and are prepared to say anything to get a visa. Add to that the fact that the German trade fair suggests Germany is the main destination even if you spend less time there, you could risk an actual refusal the second time (the motive could be ("Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable"). If staying longer in France is an option, maybe try that first?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: Yeah, you have a point. I'll just change my plans and extend my stay in France.

Comment: @egyptianlamp You did the right thing

Answer (score 0):

Just change your travel plan say you will stay 3 nights in Germany. Or say you will stay more nights in France,  you will need to book additional nights accommodation but you can cancel the booking after you got your visa. It's really that simple.  I have applied schegen visa through french ambassy couple of times without even landing in the country . All you need is a proper travel plan and accommodation booking (cancellable) that proves your plan, and the flight  tickets proves the plan, of course that needs to be cancellable (business class). It's nothing but a paperwork game. And  most importantl of all, this is all legal , you can change your plan right?

Comment: Not committing outright visa fraud has its advantages too.

Comment: It's not a fraud if I don't tell you this. I would call it playing with the rules. There are so many things people  are playing with the rules only you didn't know.

Comment: I am not a judge or jury and I do not even play a lawyer on television but my personal, non-professional belief is that this is visa fraud. Whether you are caught or not is another matter. But, again, what a random stranger suggests on the Internet is just that. You need to weigh your options and priorities.

Comment: You won't get caught that's why it's not a fraud because every piece of documentation is authentic.  A fake document then it's a fraud.

Comment: I won't get into this debate. You know and I know it's fraud as you are lying about your intentions, whether they get caught, as I said, is a different matter.

Comment: (-1) This is not a reasonable answer. Beside the fact that it is clearly fraud, the OP rightly mentioned the fact that attending a conference makes this very difficult. Even if s/he would genuinely plan to spend more time in France, it would still appear to be the motivation behind the whole trip and could make Germany the main destination.

Comment: The op can change his or her mind to stay longer in France and book accommodation for that? Then you won't call it fraud? And you won't know what's op's intention except he or she tells you?

Comment: Think about it people, it's a problem of the rule not the people. One company I worked before used to give free one day delivery if your order reached certain amount, by sending a free one day delivery code. But people got this code sent it to their friends ,families . Did we blame the  customers for this? No we changed our system. So you are actually helping them to improve their system if they do find out something .

Comment: @thotwielder It does depend on the genuineness of the OP's intention, yes, but people have been refused entry because they changed their mind. In fact, some countries even revoke visas if you cancel an hotel booking (which is clearly illegal in my view). One issue is that lying is not always easy and it's easy to trip yourself up. But all that is a different question: one of enforcement, not legality. I am not saying it can't work, mind you, it most definitely can and does for many people. But you should not say it's unambiguously legal or cannot backfire.

Comment: @thotwielder It seems you don't understand that the system already has many things in place to prevent this. Lying on your application is not as consequence-free as using a free delivery code. If you are caught at some point (during an interview, because you contradict yourself, have stamps that do not line up with your earlier applications, etc.), you can face very serious consequences (a visa annulment would for example make it extremely difficult to get another Schengen visa).

Comment: Again, I am not saying people cannot get away with this and I have no idea whether it's a 1%, 50% or 90% risk but let's not confuse everybody by pretending it's legal or it isn't fraud. Unlike sharing your free delivery code, what you are advocating is already explicitly disallowed by the regulations.

Comment: Obviously you didn't tried that so you are not sure, and you think I am the first one to do this? I didn't invent this and I know lots of people doing this without any problem. Don't confuse legal/illegal with honest/dishonest, like you never lied in your life? What I suggested is perfect legal, full stop. And op did change his plan, which is what I recommend at first place.

Comment: @thotwielder Have you even read what I have written? Obviously, there are many people who managed to do that and weren't caught, I didn't need you to discover that. The fact you did too proves nothing, it's just an anecdote, it does not tell us how likely it is to succeed. And I really don't care whether it's "honest" or not, I am not bothered by it at all. But it is, in fact, illegal.

Comment: And you did not recommend changing plans, you recommended lying about them, which is precisely what constitutes fraud. If you don't understand that distinction, you have no business telling people about what's legal or not...