# Long term Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I have been issued 2 times Schengen visa (Poland and Italy) and have travelled on both visas for good number of days and I also have a good passport travel history.

I have company known in Poland so I got the invitation and got my business visa done for Poland whereas for Italy it is as tourist.

There are no appointments available for Poland for next 3 months and I need to travel last week of November so I have to get the visa done with any other embassy.

My question is that in which embassy I should try and how I should try so that I get a tourist multiple entry 90 days stay visa with 6 months validity or 12 months validity. My last Poland visa is of 3 months validity with multiple entry 30 days stay.
As I don't have an invitation letter from any other country I am not able to think how I should request for this 90 days visa in tourist category.

Can anyone please suggest me which embassy I should apply and how I should draft a request letter so chances are good to get a long one.

As per my knowledge Switzerland, Italy and Greece should be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Everything else being equal, some countries/consulates might conceivably be more likely than others to grant a multi-year visa but it depends first and foremost on the strength of your application. The idea is that you need to have a convincing reason to visit a country repeatedly and a relationship with that consulate.

So there is no point in targetting a "soft" country if it makes your application weaker because you have no reasons to be visiting it several times. "Begging" for a multiple-entry visa with a long validity if you don't have an excellent justification isn't likely to succeed either and could even work against you. The best you can do is probably to keep trying.

Obivously, a history of using Schengen visas correctly and an otherwise very strong application (finances, ties to your country of origin) are necessary as well. Your earlier trips should help somewhat but there isn't much else you can do to push a consulate to issue a multiple-entry visa.

Finally, note that trying to get a visa from "any other embassy" to circumvent the Polish consulate isn't the right approach if what you really want to do is going to Poland. Instead, you should follow the tips in [Can I get an appointment at a French consulate different than the one assigned to my state?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t) and [Can I apply to France (Schengen visa) when my main destination is Germany because I can't book an appointment at the German consulate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74636/can-i-apply-to-france-schengen-visa-when-my-main-destination-is-germany-becaus)

Answer (score 0):

"There are no appointments available for Poland for next 3 months and I need to travel last week of November so I have to get the visa done with any other embassy."

If you don't want to appear for an interview, the Finnish embassy accepts postal applications for Schengen visa, as long as you've had a Schengen visa and fingerprints taken within the past 5 years.

http://www.finland.org/public/default.aspx?nodeid=35854&contentlan=2&culture=en-US

Comment: Of course, if the traveler isn't planning a trip to Finland, this won't be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, they will need to show some travel in Finland to do this. I was merely giving this as an option to the traveler, since they are planning to go to a non-Polish embassy anyway, while travelling to Poland as the main destination.