# Is there a way to get a visa appointment faster?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, netherlands, embassies

I need to travel to Netherlands (business trip) in a month (I live in San-Fransisco, US, not a US citizen). The problem is that when I try to [schedule an appointment](http://www.rsonac.org/other-services/8---other-logistics/schedule-an-appointment.html), the closest appointment I can get is in one and half a month (which makes my trip impossible). The site makes it clear that it is impossible to come and submit the documents without an appointment.

Is there a way to get an appointment faster (most probably by paying additional money to get a "quick appointment")?

Comment: The old trick always works, I keep checking everyday multiple times until someone who has a closer appointment cancels...

Comment: No premium service AFAIK but you could try another Dutch consulate (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/can-i-get-an-appointment-at-a-french-consulate-different-than-the-one-assigned-t) or change your plans to apply elsewhere (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48286/unable-to-get-an-appointment-at-san-francisco-italy-consulate). But the latter seems difficult and risky for a business trip as your real purpose would be transparent and it may look like you are trying to cheat. Do try to approach the Dutch consulate in any case, they might be willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, most (every?) country has two tracks for visitor visas: normal and emergency. Emergency typically is only granted for death or very serious illness of a close family member (blood relative).

https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/question-and-answer/how-do-i-apply-for-a-visa-for-the-netherlands

> Emergency visa applications
>
> If you or a family member need to visit the Netherlands urgently, you can apply for an emergency visa. To apply for an emergency visa, please contact the [Immigration and Naturalisation Service (IND)](https://ind.nl/EN/organisation/contact).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Good thing is that this is just a business trip (no one died).